# SSL connection between MySQL, Apache and the User's device

Tags: tls, apache, mysql

I set up SSL connection on my apache web server and I just would like to find out is it enough to secure my connection between the MySQL server, the apache web server and the user's device. Because I can set up SSL connection on the MySQL server too. So, do I have to set it up when the database server is on an other computer? Because I think the web server and the database server are on the same computer the MySQL SSL connection makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems quite simple to me. The final decision however, depending on the context, may not be as simple as it implies the notion of *trust*.

SSL is a protocol allowing you to establish a secure connection over an untrusted network. The usefulness of SSL in your case therefore lies in this question:

***Do you trust the network between the web server and the database server?***